# Jar Dependencies in Visual C++ Development in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, android, c++, visual-studio-2015, fmod

I'm attempting to add fmod to a cross-platform project in Visual Studio 2015.

I need to reference fmod.jar in my project, but I'm not sure how.

I've added fmod.jar (and the corresponding folders+files) into a folder I've called lib, and I've updated my project.properties to include jar.libs.dir=lib, but when I attempt to call System.loadLibrary("fmod") in my activity, it says it cannot find fmod.so.

I know it's aware of the fmod.so files during build (they are in each of the corresponding sub-folders: arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, and x86) because it complains if I move/remove any of them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solution for it? Maybe you can help on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242443/jar-dependencies-package-does-not-exist-in-visual-c-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. After installing Update 2 everything links and runs fine.